# Reading 647 CSVs in a folder, summing a column in each, and adding the sums to a new data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a folder of 647 CSVs. Inside the CSVs lies a column named "mxpx." I want to sum this column for each CSV and place the sum into a new data frame. The end result would be a 647x1 data frame with a column labeled "mxpx," each entry being a sum of mxpx from each CSV.

I have tried reading in the files and binding them together to create one dataframe with:

```r
files <- list.files(path = x, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
tbl <- sapply(files, read_csv, simplify = FALSE) %>% bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

However, I'm not sure if I can continue with this method once I have achieved a single data frame.

Is there a solution that can loop through the CSVs, sum the mxpx column, add it to a dataframe, and move to the next folder?

Comment: How are your files named?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looping over the files with `sapply`, read the data, extract (`$`) the column, and get the `sum`.  As it is a `sapply`, it will return a `vector`

```
out <- sapply(files, function(x) sum(read.csv(x)$mxpx, na.rm = TRUE))
dat <- data.frame(mxpx = out)
```